# How to change cursor color in html-editor-enhanced flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using html-editor-enhanced to compose.

I'm having problems synchronizing the cursor colors with the app's colors. when I focus on Editor, the default color of the cusor is green. while my app has a different color. How do I change the color of this cursor?
Hope to get help from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question.
In android native. > Res>value> style.xml
add this line

```
 <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#2F93EF</item>
```

Full code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#2F93EF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```